# Is the Higgs field responsible of only 1% of the proton mass?

Tags: particle-physics, mass, higgs, protons

This post is a sequel of: [Where does the majority of the mass of the usual matter come from?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/185149/26397)

The following answer of @hft:

> Your question asks why the "current quark masses" [see
>   http://pdg.lbl.gov/2011/download/rpp-2010-booklet.pdf at page 21] of
>   the quarks that make up a proton don't add up to the mass of the
>   proton. The problem is that, for the light quarks, the "current quark
>   masses" are very different from the "constituent quark masses" [see
>   wikipedia]. "Constituent quark masses" basically means: What you would
>   expect from a naive model where the proton is uud and the neutron is
>   udd. Whereas "current quark masses" means: What you would expect in a
>   mass-independent subtraction scheme such as $\bar {MS}$ at a scale of
>   $\mu\sim 2GeV$, which basically is a fancy way of saying "it's
>   complicated".
>
> The reason these are different is because the strong nuclear force
>   (AKA Quantum Chromodynamics) is "asymptotically free", i.e., it is
>   only easy to understand at very high energies in terms of single
>   particles.  At low energies, such as in protons, the "bag of quarks"
>   that make up the proton can not be thought of as single particles
>   because there is a large and difficult to determine interaction among
>   the quarks and gluons inside the proton.  This interaction energy can
>   be though of as "making up the mass difference" although it would be
>   just as good to say that a proton is NOT make up of just three quarks.
>   Rather it is made up up many many quark-anti-quark pairs and gluons on
>   top of which sit **three "extra" quarks**: u, u, and d

leads us to the following question:

**Question**: Is the Higgs field responsible of only 1% of the proton mass (through these *three "extra" quarks*)?

The following comment of @hft:

> You're on to something there, but it's hard to say exactly. The Higgs
>   can be thought of as responsible for generating all the quark mass
>   terms in the QCD Lagrangian, but it doesn't generate any mass
>   associated with interaction energy by E/c^2. Although I think it's a
>   little more complicated than this.

calls for a proper answer to the question above.

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/131487/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/3037/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/64232/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Forgive me, but are you asking specifically where the one per cent figure comes from (not that I know, I don't).

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, yes.

Even if we account for the mass of the three quarks that make up a proton, it would only make up (at most) 1% of the mass of what we measure for an entire proton. This is because of the fluctuations in the gluon field.

Now, I won't go into detail, but basically this gluon field is ever permeating, and is only absent in the area of quark pairs or trios. (These are called quantum flux tubes, a topic for another time). 
Basically it's all of this energy from the fluctuating field, constantly creating and destroying virtual particles that accounts for the majority of a mass of a proton.